# Login to Force website as User?

Tags: community, force.com, customer-portal

I would like to know how I can login to my force website as Users/Contacts? This can be done for Customer Portals and Communites but I cannot find anything to see how it can be done for Force.com websites.

[image: picture of function]

Answer (score -1):

The moment you are in a force.com site and log in, then you stop being a force.com user and become a portal user. As authenticated user you are a 'Guest' user but if you have enabled the login option for your site, then you log in as a portal user.

Comment: I understand this, but how can I have Salesforce login to the force.com website as the portal user rather than the customer portal?

Comment: I am confused, if you want to log in as the portal user just use the button you have highlighted. There is no other way in which you can use the "Log In As" function for a portal user.

Comment: I don't think you have understood the question. Portal users (portal license) can login into customer portal websites and if allowed they can also login to custom made force.com websites. What I am asking is can administrators login into force.com websites as a user like they can with a customer portal or customer community.